# Distinguish 1:M association Vs 1:M composition in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How can I distinguish a 1:M association versus a 1:M composition when adding a FK to my table?

For example, I use the query statement below to alter an existing column `Account` (in `Case` table) to a foreign key that references `AccountId` (in `Account` table).

They share a 1:M associative relationship where one account can have many cases. What if they had a 1:M composition, how would this alter statement look like? Is the statement below correct for a 1:M association?

```
Alter table [dbo].[Case] with check add constraint [FK_Case_Account] foreign key ([Account]) 
references [dbo].[Account] ([AccountId])
GO

Alter table [dbo].[Case] check constraint [FK_Case_Account]
```

Comment: What is a "1:M Composition", and how is it different from a "1:M Association"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few basics that need to be corrected in your questions.

**Association between two entities is either aggregation or composition.**

So your question does not make sense if you talk about difference between 1:M composition vs 1:M association.

To understand the difference between aggregation and composition in terms of relation DB design, I usually follow one thumb rule.

It is **definitely composition if your FK relation of type Cascade delete.**

OR

In other way, **it's definitely aggregation if your foreign key column be `NULL`**

In terms of example involving `Table A( A_ID, ..)` and `Table B(B_ID, ..)`

If you need to create Aggregation relationship either you need a mapping table say `Map_A_B(A_ID,B_ID)` or you add a A_ID FK column to Table B but make it NULL-able

If you need to create Composition relationship, you keep the mapping in mapping table but enforce a cascade delete to achieve deletion of rows in Table B and mapping table if there is a deletion of row in Table A or you add a NOT NULL A_ID FK column in Table B (like in your current case)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation makes the concept very clear. I'm going to implement this and see how it works!